# How I can create Model from collection? Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have a factory

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Polygon::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => 1,
        'sort' => 2,
        'name' => 'МКАД',
        'center' => '55.73,37.75',
        'points' => '[55.8977029,37.6724091],[55.8966419,37.6752415],
        'parent_id' => 'N20N',
        'location_id' => 'N1N',
        'lat' => 55.73,
        'lon' => 37.75,
        'xml_id' => 'N1N'
    ];
});
```

but this factory returns the collection but i need to make model for my test.

```
public function testGetRouteDistance()
{
    $polygon = factory(Polygon::class, 1)->create();
```

Are there any methods in Laravel that allow you to convert a collection into a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel returns a model by default, with this:

```
public function testGetRouteDistance()
{
    $polygon = factory(Polygon::class)->make();

    // Use model in tests...

}
```

A collection is returned when you provide a second parameter like this:

```
public function testGetRouteDistance()
{
    $polygon = factory(Polygon::class, 3)->make();

    // Use model in tests...

}
```